# Escrever em arquivo txt com PHP

Tags: php, txt

Possuo um arquivo `txt` porém está faltando o `nome` em várias linhas do arquivo, gostaria de por o nome conforme o número de pedido.

A lógica seria verificar o número do pedido da linha que está sem o nome no caso o pedido `203885`, procurar outra linha que possui o mesmo número do pedido e que tenha nome, pegar este nome e copiar ele para todos números de pedidos iguais. ***Porém os números de pedidos que não são iguais possuem nomes diferentes. A coluna que representa os pedidos é a coluna 2.***

Arquivo Original txt:

```
100400;205537;30141;BALCAO 1 PORTA PER 400X670X500;MDF BP BRANCO;6;79281905;NOME1;0205537006
100400;203885;50058;PAI OPC EDIT LARGX ALTX 25;BLANCHE#695#320;18;79283198;NOME;0203885018
100400;205537;100001;EMBALAGEM DE FERRAGENS DIVERSAS;                                ;35;79283215;                              ;0203885035
100400;203885;101619;EMBALAGEM DE FUNDOS DORMITORIO;                                ;36;79283216;                              ;0203885036
```

Após modificado deve ficar assim:

```
100400;205537;30141;BALCAO 1 PORTA PER 400X670X500;MDF BP BRANCO;6;79281905;NOME1;0205537006
100400;203885;50058;PAI OPC EDIT LARGX ALTX 25;BLANCHE#695#320;18;79283198;NOME;0203885018
100400;205537;100001;EMBALAGEM DE FERRAGENS DIVERSAS;                                ;35;79283215;NOME1;0203885035
100400;203885;101619;EMBALAGEM DE FUNDOS DORMITORIO;                                ;36;79283216;NOME;0203885036
```

*Basta modificar no arquivo não é necessario imprimir na tela.*

Comment: o nome será igual para todos e deve estar nesse espaço vazio?

Comment: Se entendi direito, teria que comparar `$linha[6]` se não existe pegue o valor anteior (que está em outra variavel) . vc quer apenas imprimir isso na tela?

Comment: Eu quero alterar no arquivo mesmo imprimir em tela não é necessario, e sim é no espaço vazio que deve conter o nome.

Comment: descreva qual coluna representa os  códigos dos pedidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kelvin teria como fazer o seguinte, mostre como está em txt e também como quer o resultado, pra eu poder compreender e ajudar melhor.
A um tempo atrás eu fiz um post sobre correção UTF-8 o qual analisa um arquivo em questão e corrige e cria um novo, Vou deixar o link aqui pode ser útil. 
http://www.bulfaitelo.com.br/2016/10/como-reparar-problema-com-caracteres-em.html

Fiz um código que verificar o txt gera um vetor com todos os números e respectivos nomes juntamente de um novo vetor com todas as informações, após isso percorro novamente o vetor já corrigindo o campo que está faltando, com isso corrigindo os nomes. e por fim crio novamente os itens separados por ";"

Atente para o código:

```
<?php

$file_name = "IMP.txt";

$file = fopen($file_name, "r") or die ("Arquivo não encontrado!");
$file_output = fopen("Output_".$file_name, "w") or die ("Arquivo não criado!");
// Gerando o vetor para tratamento
while(!feof($file)){    
    $strAnalise =  fgets($file) ;
    $strAnaliseArray = explode(";", $strAnalise);
    if(trim($strAnaliseArray[7]) != ''){
        $ArrayChaveNome[$strAnaliseArray[1]] = trim($strAnaliseArray[7]);
    }
    $strArrayDados[]=$strAnaliseArray;
}
// Corrindo o vetor;
foreach ($strArrayDados as $key => $value) {
    if(trim($value[7]) == ''){
        if(array_key_exists($value[1], $ArrayChaveNome)){
            $strArrayDados[$key][7]= $ArrayChaveNome[$value[1]];
        }
    }
}
// retornando a ";"
foreach ($strArrayDados as $key => $value) {
    $resultPontoVirgula.= implode(";", $value);
    $resultPontoVirgulaToTxt= implode(";", $value);
    fwrite($file_output, $resultPontoVirgulaToTxt);
}   
// var_dump($strArrayDados);
// var_dump($strAnaliseArray);
var_dump($resultPontoVirgula);

fclose($file_output);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Script de testes

```
/*
Esse array simula a relação entre os códigos dos pedidos e os nomes
*/
$orders = array(
    '205537' => 'FULANO 1',
    '203885' => 'FULANO 2'
);

/*
Dados para teste
*/
$data = '100400;205537;30141;BALCAO 1 PORTA PER 400X670X500;MDF BP BRANCO;6;79281905;NOME;0205537006
100400;203885;50058;PAI OPC EDIT LARGX ALTX 25;BLANCHE#695#320;18;79283198;NOME;0203885018
100400;203885;100001;EMBALAGEM DE FERRAGENS DIVERSAS;                                ;35;79283215;                              ;0203885035
100400;203885;101619;EMBALAGEM DE FUNDOS DORMITORIO;                                ;36;79283216;                              ;0203885036';

/*
Essa é a parte que interessa.
*/
$arr = explode("\n", $data);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $csv[$k] = str_getcsv($v, ';');
    $csv[$k][7] = $orders[$csv[$k][1]];
    $csv[$k] = implode(';', $csv[$k]);
}
$data = implode("\n", $csv);
echo $data;
```

## Implementação final

```
$orders = array(
    '205537' => 'FULANO 1',
    '203885' => 'FULANO 2'
);

$file = '/local/do/arquivo.txt';
$arr = file($file);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $csv[$k] = str_getcsv($v, ';');
    $csv[$k][7] = $orders[$csv[$k][1]];
    $csv[$k] = implode(';', $csv[$k]);
}
file_put_contents($file, (implode("\n", $csv));
```

Esteja ciente que isso não é otimizado para arquivos pesados, com mais de 100MB, por exemplo.

Comment: Só que ai que vem o problema, eu não vou poder setar manual o NOME ai no replace ele tem que ser dinamico. Pois o nome varia para cada número de pedido. Cada pedido é um nome não será sempre o mesmo. Por exemplo o pedido 203885 vai ter o nome "teste1" e o pedido 205537 "teste2" então para todos pedidos 203885 tem que preencher com o nome "teste1" e para o  205537 "teste2".

Comment: Eu já editei na pergunta, está no segundo parágrafo.

Comment: Vê se agora está mais claro.