# Como salvar o resultado do while para um arquivo txt?

Tags: php, txt

Gera o txt, mas salva somente a última inserção do banco e no caso preciso de todos os dados.

```
$querymail = mysql_query("select mat,nome from usuario ");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
    $log = str_pad($data[0], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $log1 = str_pad($data[1], 40, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    $linhas = "log1$log2.";         
}
```

Comment: 1) Não utilize mais as funções `mysql_*`, elas estão obsoletas. 2) Pesquise sobre a função [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php). 3) Faltou um `$` na variável `$conexao` na última linha.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Escrever em arquivo txt com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163378/escrever-em-arquivo-txt-com-php)

Comment: Não é duplicada, situações diferentes.

Comment: Faça a pesquisa indicada, tente fazer uma solução e se der erro, volte e edite a pergunta com o código e a mensagem de erro. Use a pergunta que o Daniel indicou como material de estudo também. Nela tem a solução que você precisa, basta analisar o código.

Comment: Fiz o sugerido, mas o problema persiste...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando file_put_contents escreve uma string em um arquivo, caso este arquivo ainda não exista ele cria o arquivo

```
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
       $log = str_pad($data[0], 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
       $log1 = str_pad($data[1], 40, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

        $linhas .= $log. " " .$log1."\n";         
    }

file_put_contents('arquivo.txt', $linhas);
```

> Se você quiser apenas acrescentar um valor em um arquivo já criado, você terá que utilizar um terceiro parâmetro com o valor FILE_APPEND, ficando assim:

```
file_put_contents('arquivo.txt', $linhas, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Leo, implementadndo sua solução continua aparecendo apenas uma linha, teria outra orientação?

Comment: quantas linhas esse while retorna?

Comment: o objetivo é retornar todos os dados da tabela, nesse caso uns 200 registros

Comment: $linhas .= $log. " " .$log1."\n";  acumula todos esses dados é o mesmo que $linhas = $linhas .  $log. " " .$log1."\n";

Comment: Fiz um novo teste implementando sua orientação e funcionou da seguinte forma. O arquivo gerado no servidor consta todos os dados e o que está sendo baixado continua com uma linha.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59047/discussion-between-leo-caracciolo-and-checktech).